# OpenCL with c++ wrapper - how to convert cl::CommandQueue to cl_command_queue?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am using OpenCL with the CL/cl.hpp c++ wrappers.
So I have c++ objects such as  e.g. `cl::CommandQueue` instead of `cl_command_queue`.

I am also wanting to use AMD's BLAS library, clAmdBlas.  The functions there require a `cl_command_queue` as one of their arguments.

How do I get `cl_command_queue` from `cl::CommandQueue`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the `cl_command_queue` object, you simply need to use the `()` operator:

```
cl::CommandQueue cppQueue;
...
cl_command_queue queue = cppQueue();
```

The same goes for all of the other C++ objects in this header that are wrapping OpenCL runtime objects.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Some other objects like cl::Buffer had functions to return the wrapped item, listed on e.g. the OpenCL reference card.  But for cl::CommandQueue I could not find one.  Good to know how to do it now :)

Answer (score 4):

In `cl.hpp`, `cl::CommandQueue` is defined as such:

```
class CommandQueue : public detail::Wrapper<cl_command_queue>
```

And `detail::Wrapper<T>` is defined as such:

```
template <typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    typedef T cl_type;

protected:
    cl_type object_;

public:
    cl_type operator ()() const { return object_; }
    cl_type& operator ()() { return object_; }

    ...
};
```

So you can do:

```
cl::CommandQueue commandQueue = cl::CommandQueue(...);
cl_command_queue queue = commandQueue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Seems I can only select 1 right answer, sorry I can't mark yours also.